# Math expression that doesn't work with a parenthesis

Tags: java

I'm tryng to convert a Fahrenheit temperature in correspective Celsius so I wrote:

```
double f = 90.0;
double c = (90.0-32)*(5/9); // 0.0
```

But this don't works, better fortune if I don't use the second set of parenthesis:

```
double c = (90.0-32)*5/9; // 32.2222
```

Why this (at least for me) strange behavior?

Answer (score 3):

Don't use integers in division since `2/5 = 0` but `2.0/5.0 = 0.4`

Answer (score 2):

Your problem is here

```
double c = (90.0-32)*(5/9);
```

the integer division of 5 and 9 is going to result in the value zero. Change one of 5 or 9 to double value:

```
double c = (90.0-32)*(5.0/9);
```

When you divide integers, the result will be an integer and of course an integer cannot store the true fraction value of result, only the integer part of it.

Answer (score 2):

`(90.0-32)*5/9` is evaluated as `((90.0-32)*5)/9`, note that the division happens between a double and an int (which is then implicitly cast to double).

In `(90.0-32)*(5/9)` there is `5/9`, which is zero.

Answer (score 2):

(5/9) will give 0 so do something like (5.0/9.0)

The second one:

```
double c = (90.0-32)*5/9;
```

works, because the expression in parenthesis is a float which you then again multiply and divide with a number so the final result stays a float.

Answer (score 2):

Try it this way.....

This example shows that when **x and y are integers the value returned is 0, but in case x and y are double then its 0.5555555555555556**

```
public class Test{
    public static void main(String[] args){

        double x = 5.0;
        double y = 9.0;

        System.out.println((90.0-32.0)*(x/y));
    }

}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can try the following things while initializing the variables.

```
double f = 90D ;
float fl = 50F ;
```

Hence you will not have to process every time the `.0` for values.

Answer (score 1):

In numerical expressions using different data types, unless specified the default choices would be `int` and `double`.

Read more details on [*Primitive Data Types*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/datatypes.html).

> 1. ***int** data type is generally the default choice unless there is a reason*.
> 2. *For decimal values, **double** data type is generally the default choice.*

In your expression :

```
double c = (90.0-32)*(5/9); // 0.0
```

1. `5` and `9` in expression `(5/9)` are considered as `int` data types and hence
   the result of division is `0`, an `int`.
2. expression `(90.0-32)` would be resulting a `double`, since `32` is an `int`.
   You may be knowing that
   2.1. `double */+/- int/long/float/double` would result a `double`.
   2.2. `double divided_by_any int/long/float/double` would result a `double`.

Keeping in mind the above points, expression for `c` can be interpreted as

```
double c = (double)*(int);
double c = (90.0-32)*(0);
double c = 0.0; // double
```

Hence the result for `c` would be a `double` `0.0`.

The expression

```
double c = (90.0-32)*5/9; // 32.2222
```

is interpreted, based on [*operator precedence*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/operators.html), as

```
double c = ( (90.0-32)*5 ) / 9; // ( (double - int) * int ) / int
//c = ( (58.0)*5 ) / 9; // ( (double) * int ) / int
//c = ( 290.0 ) / 9; // ( double ) / int
c = 32.22222222222222; // double
```

---

Alternatively, an explicit cast of `5` or `9` in `(5/9)` to a `double` would result `32.22222222222222` for `c`.

```
//double c = (90.0-32)*(5/9);
double c = (90.0-32)*( (double)5/9 ); // (double - int) * ( (double)int / int )
// or
//double c = (90.0-32)*( 5/(double)9 ); // (double - int) * ( int / (double)int )

//c = (58.0)*(5.0/9); // ( (double) * ( double / int )
//c = (58.0)*(0.5555555555555556); // ( double )*( double )
c = 32.22222222222222; // double
```

To understand more about unambiguous expressions and statements, please also refer to :
[*Expressions, Statements, and Blocks*](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/expressions.html)